# Not able to overlap position absolute div over relative div

Tags: html, css-position, z-index

I want my yellow box overlap on red box. Means part of red box should hide behind yellow box. Even the z-index of yellow box is higher than red box.
Below is the jsfiddle

```
 <div style="width:40px;height:100px;">
<div id="relative">
    <div class="absolute">yellow</div>
</div>
<div id="relative" style="top: 54px">red</div>
</div>

#relative {
    position: relative;
    /* width: 40px; */
    height: 80px;
    background: #f00;
    z-index: 0;
    /* margin-top: 30px; */
}
.absolute {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 12;
    width: 200px;
    height: 150px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/P7c9q/1036/)

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Absolute position relative to above div. You can make red div absolute and show it behind yellow div

```
<div style="width:40px;height:100px;">
    <div id="relative">
        <div class="absolute">yellow</div>
        <div style="position:absolute; top: 130px; background: #f00; height: 80px;">red</div>
    </div>    
</div>

 #relative {
        position: relative;
    }
    .absolute {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: 12;
        width: 200px;
        height: 150px;
        background: yellow;
    }
```